# Combine Grouped and Stacked Bar Graph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, stacked-chart

The following is how my data frame looks like:

```
CatA    CatB   CatC 
1        Y      A
1        N      B
1        Y      C
2        Y      A
3        N      B
2        N      C 
3        Y      A
4        Y      B
4        N      C 
5        N      A
5        Y      B
```

I want to have CatA on X-Axis, and its count on Y-Axis. This graph comes fine. However, I want to create group for CatB and stack it with CatC keeping count in Y axis. This is what I have tried, and this is how it looks:

[image]

I want it to look like this:

[image]

My code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(factor(data$catA), data$catB, fill = data$catC)) 
+ geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "stack") 
+ theme_bw() + facet_grid( ~ data$catC)
```

PS: I am sorry for providing links to images because I am not able to upload it, it gives me error occurred at imgur, every time I upload.

Comment: your `ggplot` code contains different data then what you shared above.

Comment: I just shortened the dataset and drew a final approximate graph for how it would look like. The main point is, CatB needs to be grouped, and C needs to be stacked keeping CatA on xaxis and its count on Yaxis. Am I clear now?

Comment: can you make your code consistent in  that case?

Comment: Is it better now? Just edited to make it more readable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use facets:

```
df <- data.frame(A = sample(1:5, 30, T), 
                 B = sample(c('Y', 'N'), 30, T), 
                 C = rep(LETTERS[1:3], 10))

ggplot(df) + geom_bar(aes(B, fill = C), position  = 'stack', width = 0.9) + 
  facet_wrap(~A, nrow = 1) + theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"))
```

[image]

Comment: This works like a charm. Never new about these facets, much simpler to do using the same. Thanks a ton, mate!

Comment: Very cool! That's by far the most elegant solution I have seen regarding this kind of question!