# Stacked and grouped bar chart in ggplot while maintaining y scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, stacked-bar-chart

I am working on a project where I am analysing phytoplankton data using R and trying to assess the pattern of how pigment ratios change over the year.

The code for one of my plots is given below. It is working well (see ![Valid jpg] [plot by sample ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eILDZ.png)) in that is is plotting the pigments as ratios of 100%, which is what I want, since we are looking at relative pigment ratios.

However, there is no clear time variable (I want the month to be apparent). If I change the `x aes` to `month`, the stacked plots sum to different values because there are different numbers of datapoints for each month (see [plot by month](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fQgO.png)).

I have tried using `facet_wrap(~month)` but this makes the data unclear in my opinion. Ideally, I would have the bars still summing to 100% as in `seq`, but with some clear separation by `month` too, so that I could make something like the photo
[pigments with depth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjaM6.png) (which I made using a different approach), but with separation by month.

I hope that this is clear - it is quite a complicated problem and this is my first time asking a question, so I hope it wasn't too waffly!

```
plot_data <- shallowest_sample %>%select(all_of(selected_columns)) %>%pivot_longer(cols = -c(Id, lat, lon, depth, Unique_ID,decy,seq,month), names_to = "Pigment", values_to = "Percentage") %>%mutate(Pigment = sub("^normalised_", "", Pigment)) %>%group_by(month)

pigment_ratios_shallow <- ggplot(plot_data, aes(fill = factor(Pigment), y = Percentage, x = seq)) 
    + geom_bar(position = 'stack', stat = 'identity') 
    + labs(title = "Normalized Accessory Pigment Distribution for surface waters",x = "Sample ID",y = "Percentage") 
    + scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(scale = 100))
    + theme_minimal()
pigment_ratios_shallow
```

As suggested in the comments, here is a sample of the data I wish to plot:
structure(list(Id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), lat = c(31.667, 31.667,
31.667, 31.667, 31.667, 31.667, 31.667, 31.667, 31.667, 31.667,
31.667, 31.667, 31.667, 31.667, 31.667, 31.667, 31.667, 31.667,
31.667, 31.667), lon = c(-64.105, -64.105, -64.105, -64.105,
-64.105, -64.105, -64.105, -64.105, -64.105, -64.105, -64.105,
-64.105, -64.105, -64.105, -64.105, -64.105, -64.105, -64.105,
-64.105, -64.105), depth = c(3.7, 3.7, 3.7, 3.7, 3.7, 3.7, 3.7,
3.7, 3.7, 3.7, 10.9, 10.9, 10.9, 10.9, 10.9, 10.9, 10.9, 10.9,
10.9, 10.9), Unique_ID = c("200211131416", "200211131416", "200211131416",
"200211131416", "200211131416", "200211131416", "200211131416",
"200211131416", "200211131416", "200211131416", "200211131416",
"200211131416", "200211131416", "200211131416", "200211131416",
"200211131416", "200211131416", "200211131416", "200211131416",
"200211131416"), decy = c(2002.86738, 2002.86738, 2002.86738,
2002.86738, 2002.86738, 2002.86738, 2002.86738, 2002.86738, 2002.86738,
2002.86738, 2002.86738, 2002.86738, 2002.86738, 2002.86738, 2002.86738,
2002.86738, 2002.86738, 2002.86738, 2002.86738, 2002.86738),
Pigment = c("peridin", "19.but", "fuco", "19.hex", "prasino",
"diadino", "allo", "abcarotene", "lutein", "zea", "peridin",
"19.but", "fuco", "19.hex", "prasino", "diadino", "allo",
"abcarotene", "lutein", "zea"), Percentage = c(0.015625,
0.09375, 0.078125, 0.140625, 0.03125, 0.0625, 0.015625, 0.046875,
0.015625, 0.5, 0.0151515151515152, 0.106060606060606, 0.0757575757575758,
0.136363636363636, 0.0303030303030303, 0.0606060606060606,
0.0151515151515152, 0.0454545454545455, 0.0151515151515152,
0.5)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl",
"data.frame"))

Comment: It's much easier for people to offer constructive, specific suggestions if you can provide some sort of data sample that has the characteristics of your data. This is often easiest by running `dput(head(plot_data, 20))`, where "20" is a number of rows that is just enough to be useful, (e.g. 2-3 id's worth), and pasting the output of that into the body of your question, which you are encouraged to edit.

Comment: Good point! I have edited my original question now :)

Answer (score 0):

Third attempt; I am new in answering here.
`position_fill()` seems to be usefull. I am not sure what you want on the X-axis, I used the month-id interaction. Maybe by playing with the space between the bars, you could increase the readability.

[image]

```
library(tidyverse)
# Making a dataframe
df = tibble(  id = rep(1:30), # 30 ID
              month = c( rep(1, 15), rep(2, 10),rep(3, 5)), # Unequal month numbers
              comp1= 0.1 ,  # Fist component: constant
              comp2 = rnorm(30, mean = 0.5, sd = 0.1)# Second component: random
) %>% 
  mutate(comp3 = 1- comp1 - comp2) # Third component: 1 - others


df %>% pivot_longer(comp1:comp3) %>% 
  group_by(id, name) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x= interaction(month %>% as.factor(), id %>% as.factor), fill =name,y =value,
             group=id)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", col="black", position = 
             position_fill() )
```

Second answer:
You could normalize by the number of sample per month.

```
df = tibble(  id = rep(1:30), # 30 ID
              month = c( rep(1, 15), rep(2, 10),rep(3, 5)), # Unequal month numbers
              comp1= 0.1 ,  # Fist component: constant
              comp2 = rnorm(30, mean = 0.5, sd = 0.1)# Second component: random
              ) %>% 
  mutate(comp3 = 1- comp1 - comp2) # Third component: 1 - others


df %>% pivot_longer(comp1:comp3) %>% 
  group_by( month,name) %>% 
  mutate( n = n()) %>% 
  mutate(standardiez_value= value/n) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=month %>% as.factor(), fill =name, y= standardiez_value,
             group=name)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", col="black")
```

[image: bar plot with ID]

Versus my old answer (below), we can the varibility by component. However, the unequality of the dataset add a difficulty to read the graph.

I still  think that I don't represent the data the right way, but it's difficult to understand what you really want.

First answer:

If I understand correctly, you want to represent the average of each component for each month. My suggestion is to compute the monthly average for each month. I made an unequal dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)
df = tibble(  id = rep(1:30), # 30 ID
              month = c( rep(1, 15), rep(2, 10),rep(3, 5)), # Unequal month numbers
              comp1= 0.1 ,  # Fist component: constant
              comp2 = rnorm(30, mean = 0.5, sd = 0.2)# Second component: random
              ) %>% 
  mutate(comp3 = 1- comp1 - comp2) # Third component: 1 - others
```

Then I `pivot_longer()`, `group_by()` and `summarise()`, before ploting.

```
df %>% pivot_longer(comp1:comp3) %>% 
  group_by( month,name) %>%  summarise(mean = mean(value)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=month %>% as.factor(), fill =name, y= mean)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image: Example of the bar plot]

Comment: This post seems also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45056382/13203906

Comment: Thank you Vince! This was really helpful - the position_fill is not exactly what I wanted, but it basically does the job. I think I'm going to go with your third solution for now and perhaps just make my depth plot an average of all measurements month by month!

Thanks,